# Magento 2 change varnish settings

Tags: magento2

Like a lot of other users i have a problem with displaying my navigation bar in magento 2 with Luma theme and varnish. I found out that changing a varnish setting can solve the problem (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99768/magento-2-https-ssl-missing-navigation-menu/100128#100128), but how to change that setting in a default magento 2.1.3 configuration?

Also, how do i check the version and working of Varnish? if i simply use varnishd -V in ssh, there comes an error message...

Update: When I remove the TTL attribute in default.xml  the problem is solved, the menubar is there again. But can that cause any other problems?

Answer (score 0):

The performance of a website is always the key factor for ensuring a higher conversion rate. Fortunately, Magento 2 (both CE & EE) comes by default with the support for FPC (Full Page Caching), Varnish & Redis to make your store fly.

To setup varnish in Magento 2, please follow the given instructions in below URL.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-varnish-setup/

Comment: Abhinav, I already did that. And performance is vey good, but my navigation bar is still missing....

Comment: Hi Jilco, which Magento version do you use and also tell your varnish version?

Comment: I have recently been having the issue that when Varnish was enabled, the navigation bar didn't appear.
What I discovered was Varnish wasn't parsing the ESI tags, instead they were output to the frontend. In your source code search for a snippet like the given code:
<esi:include src="url/of/your/site" />
If you find any "esi" tags on your page, then your Varnish config is incorrect and needs to be updated to enable "esi". After I updated my Varnish config to enable esi, everything started working as expected and the menu re-appeared.

Comment: Abhinav, sounds like a plan :-). But I'm using the build in varnish version of Magento, so how to change config over there? Is there a place in the magento root to edit the varnish config?

Comment: When I ask for version of Varnish in SSH it says Magento 2.1.3 CLI

Comment: Like mentioned in the update, when I remove the TTL attribute in the default.xml (in de magento theme map) the problem is solved. Can that do any harm?